# what is [[prototype]] in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Referring to the following example (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain), why do I get error (using `nodejs`) when I write `o.[[Prototype]]` but not when I write `o.__proto__`

```
var o = {
    a: 1,
    b:2
}
o.[[Prototype]] = {b:1, c:3}; //doesn't work
o.__proto__= {b:1, c:3}; //works
console.log(o.a);
console.log(o.b);
console.log(o.c);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[[Prototype]]` is an internal property used by the Javascript Virtual Machine (the program that actually reads and executes the code you write). You can have read access to it in certain debuggers (like the one in Chrome) but it is not available to you in a code context. The property that is identical and *is* available is the `__proto__` property which designates your object's parent with respect to the inheritance structure of your Javascript types.